# Alerting framework for incoming traffic

Tags: mysql, alert

Currently I put hourly traffic (total number of input requests) of my website in a `MySQL` table. I keep data for the last 90 days.

I want to check every hour, lets say 6th hour, that has the traffic increased/decreased beyond some threshold than last 7 days or last 30 days 6th hour traffic. Basically, I see a pattern of traffic. Different hours have different values.

-> Is there some alerting framework which I can use as it is for this purpose?
-> If yes, can someone suggest some open source?

-> If no, I am thinking of keeping running average of last 7 days / last 30 days in a `MySQL` table for every hour. **And according, write a script to generate alerts based on those numbers. I am not very sure whether I should be mean, median or standard deviation. Can someone enlighten me there?**

Comment: I've found Sensu to be a nice, scalable open source solution for monitoring, metrics, and alerts (it's a fairly generic framework). Maybe overkill for this situation, though; I might start with a simple script and put it in a cronjob.